# Makefile recipe for target failed when executing phony command

Tags: makefile

The follow makefile is created for generate the difference from two files,
*file1* and *file2*:

```
.PHONY: patch
patch:
    diff file1 file2 > file12.patch
```

The content of *file1*:

```
xxx
```

and *file2*:

```
xxx
yyy
```

But when I issued `make patch`, error comes:

```
diff file1 file2 > file12.patch
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'patch' failed
make: *** [patch] Error 1
```

However, patch could be generated in terminal by:
`diff file1 file2 > file12.patch`.

Content of *file12.patch*:

```
1a2
> yyy
```

Surprisingly, I went back to check the folder, the `make patch` did produce the right patch file.

What I cannot understand is the make error? e.g. This error certainly will stop the make process, skip all the commands afterward.

Could someone explain this make behavior? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quoted makefile above cannot be create: recipes for `.PHONY` targets are ignored.  It must be something like:

```
.PHONY: patch
patch:
        diff file1 file2 > file12.patch
```

Make determines that a command succeeded or failed by looking at its exit code.  If the exit code is 0 then make assumes the command succeeded.  If it's non-0 make assumes it failed.

The error you're seeing implies that the `diff` command exited with a non-0 exit code.

The manual for diff says:

*An exit status of 0 means no differences were found, 1 means some
differences were found, and 2 means trouble.*

So, since your diff does find some differences it exits with a code of 1, which make interprets as failing.  You'll probably want to change your recipe to something like:

```
.PHONY: patch
patch:
        diff file1 file2 > file12.patch || [ $? -eq 1 ]
```

so if the `diff` fails you further check to see if the exit code was 2 or not.

Comment: Fix: Last exit status `$?` in Makefile should be written as `$$?`.